# Changing the displayed database tables in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Preface, I am extremely new to Database Design, MVC and .NET in general. It has been a very steep learning curve but I got my basic display down. I'm hoping someone can explain to me how I need to go about this.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application

I've followed this tutorial to a tee, using my already existing database. My next concern is how do I edit the page, to display only certain columns from my database, without messing up the code? When I take out the `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().AppName)` in the `index.cshtml` file, it messes up the order in which the data is displayed. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this, because most of the code has been generated automatically.

If anyone can explain this better to me I would greatly appreciate it. Or if you know of a great resource, I would appreciate that as well. You get to a point where looking at tutorials, when you don't really understand the information to begin with, only goes so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the `@Html.DisplayNameFor`, that will remove the column header. you need to make sure you also remove the surrounding `<td>...</td>` and also the respective `@Html.DisplayFor` call.

Comment: Such an easy thing. Thank you that was in fact my issue,  forgot to remove the @Html.DisplayFor call. Thank you so much for the help!!